# How do I get a value from a CSV file (JS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, fs

My code:

```js
fs.createReadStream('wmcsv.csv')
                .pipe(csv())
                .on('data', (row) => {
                    console.log(row);

                })
                .on('end', () => {
                    console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
                });
```

The user inputs `searchItem`.

How do I make it so that the program only outputs the `row` if the value `Name` = `searchItem`?

A row looks like this:

```js
{
 'Name':'Name1',
 'Age': 'Age1',
 'Username':'Username1'
}
```

Comment: Can you quote the header and few lines of CSV file too?

Comment: Also, please provide actual copy-paste of the output of `console.log(row)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(${row['Name']} == searchItem) {
   console.log(row)
}
```

Comment: this doesn't print anything.

Comment: please note: `console.log(row.Name);` also prints `undefined`

Comment: does row return an array?

Comment: For some reason my code makes `Name` to be in quotation marks. How can I stop this?